# mod_rewrite parameters for Silex being in a subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, silex, public-html

I was figuring out how to clean the URL for my Silex app being in a subdir of my apache server. This is the actual path: `/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/silex` with the following subdirs:

```
public_html/
    css/
    images/
    js/
    .htaccess
    index.php
src/
templates/
vendor/
```

So, if I go to: `http://www.mydomain.com/silex/public_html/` I'll find my Silex app that is working properly, but in the URL you can see the `public_html/` dir. I'd like to hide it somehow since that all my pages such as `about/`, `contacts/`, etc. will always contain that subdir in front of them.

How to avoid that?

Here's my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Basically, I just would like that my URLs become like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/silex/about
http://www.mydomain.com/silex/contacts
http://www.mydomain.com/silex/admin
(etc...)
```

Instead of:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/silex/public_html/about
http://www.mydomain.com/silex/public_html/contacts
http://www.mydomain.com/silex/public_html/admin
(etc...)
```

Thanks very much to all! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple options (you must put all of them in the .htaccess of the first public_html):

1. Make a catch-all RewriteRule and use index.php to show different content
   `RewriteRule ^silex\/(.*)$ silex/public_html/index.php?screen=$1 [NC]` - With this one, you can then catch the variable in index.php with $_GET['screen'] and load any content you wish accordingly.
2. Or you can make specific rules to redirect to specific pages `RewriteRule ^silex\/about$ silex/public_html/about.php` | `RewriteRule ^silex\/contacts$ silex/public_html/contacts.html` etc.

Let me know if you have any further questions.